# A space where set of accumulation points is not necessarily closed

Tags: general-topology

I know that this holds in a T1 space but I can't come up with a non T1 space in which this fails to be true.

A point x is an accumulation point of a set A if every neighborhood of x meets A at points other than x.

I'm looking at X={a,b,c}

Can anyone give an example?

Thank you

Comment: What is your definition of accumulation point?

Comment: What do you mean by the set of accumulation points? The set of accumulation points of some specific subset?

Comment: Yes, I want to come up with an example where the set of accumulation points of a subset of X need not be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$, $\tau=\{\varnothing, \{a,c\}, X\}$, and $A=\{a,b\}$. Then set $\{b,c\}$ of accumulation points of the set $A$ is not closed.

Comment: Oh! I forgot that A need only be a subset of X, it doesn't have to be in $\tau$. Thank you :)